# accessing Flink's system metrics in code to terminal rather than using any metrics reporter like JMX

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have used JMX as a metric reporter to get the Flink metrics, but is there any way to get it as output in the terminal?

I want to plot `numRecordsInPerSecond` for each operator for performance analysis, how can I do it?

I have seen some example of accumulators but It did not gave me the proper insight how do I do performance analysis of Flink. I will give you an example here

[image]

This is the execution plan of my Flink program, I have multiple questions, but I want to ask basic one

1. how can I measure the latency by each operator and then add it up to compute total latency for a Complex event.
2. how do I measure output throughput? Currently, I have written some code in select function which counts # of complex events seen and time Flink engine is up. Is this the best way to do it ?

But the basic question remains, which is how can I get the output for system metrics mentioned at [Flink metrics](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/monitoring/metrics.html#statsd-orgapacheflinkmetricsstatsdstatsdreporter) via code to be shown in terminal output, as I want to plot graph for performance and the problem with JMX is that it shows me metrics on demand in the sense , I see the values as I click that particular metric in JMX console, which is not perfect fit for analyzing the system.

P.S - I have found one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587645/throughput-and-latency-on-apache-flink?rq=1) asked at StackOverflow for computing throughput and latency and the answer was something like this

```java
private static class MyMapper extends RichMapFunction<String, Object> {

    private transient Meter meter;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        this.meter = getRuntimeContext()
                .getMetricGroup()
                .meter("myMeter", new DropwizardMeterWrapper(new com.codahale.metrics.Meter()));
    }

    @Override
    public Object map(String value) throws Exception {    
        this.meter.markEvent();
        return value;
    }
}
```

I have added above class in my code as well but haven't seen any output, and I also wonder how this code will show throughput or latency as we have not mentioned for which operator we want to find latency? For example, I want to find throughput for an operator somewhere in the middle of execution plan rather than at end of plan, will the above code do it for me?

Comment: You can add extra metric reporter: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html#ganglia-orgapacheflinkmetricsgangliagangliareporter. One way is define your own reporter, making all Flink jobs send their metrics to your own reporter and do whatever you'd like. Another way is retrieving metrics through Flink's REST API: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/rest_api.html

Comment: can you please provide me with an example code how my reporter can measure latency for an operator for instance

Comment: Chesnay Schepler has shared a log4j metrics reporter at https://github.com/zentol/log4jreporter, you might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You already have all the latency and Number of records per second In/Out at for each component listed out on the Flink Dashboard there is no need to implement an extra custom counter or metrics for calculating the records per second In/Out for each component.

And if you want to implement your own counter/Meter then you need this code and you have to map it to whichever component you are targetting.

Answer (score 0):

To get the metric output in terminal maybe you can use SLF4j Metric Reporter.

Put this in your flink-conf.yaml file

```
metrics.reporter.slf4j.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.slf4j.Slf4jReporterFactory
metrics.reporter.slf4j.interval: 1 SECONDS
```

And you can monitor the log using the terminal, for example:

```
tail -f taskmanager-log.log
```

Source: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/deployment/metric_reporters/#slf4j