# Measuring event-time latency with Flink CEP

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

I have implemented a pattern with Flink CEP that matches three Events such as `A->B->C`. After I have defined my pattern I generate a

`PatternStream<Event> patternStream = CEP.pattern(eventStream, pattern);`

with a `PatternSelectFunction` such that

`patternStream.select(new MyPatternSelectFunction()).print();`

This works like a charm but I am interested in the event-time of all matched events. I know that the traditional Flink streaming API offers rich functions which allow you to register Flink's internal latency tracker as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587645/throughput-and-latency-on-apache-flink?rq=1). I have also seen that for Flink 1.8 a new `RichPatternSelectFunction` has been added. But unfortunately I cannot set up Flink 1.8 with Flink CEP.

Finally, is there a way to get the event-time of all matched events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need Rich Functions to use Flink's latency tracking. You just need to enable it by setting `latencyTrackingInterval` to a positive number in either the Flink configuration or ExecutionConfig, e.g.,

```
env.getConfig().setLatencyTrackingInterval(1000);
```

and then you can observe the results in your metrics solution, or via the REST api (latency metrics are not reported in the Flink web UI).

[Documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/monitoring/metrics.html#latency-tracking)

Update:

The latency statistics are job metrics, and are in the list returned by

```
http://<job_manager_rest_endpoint>/jobs/<job_id>/metrics
```

Latency metric values can be fetched from

```
http://<job_manager_rest_endpoint>/jobs/<job_id>/metrics?get=<metric_name>
```

These metrics have names like

```
latency.source_id.<ID>.operator_id.<ID>.operator_subtask_index.<SUBTASK>.<metric>
```

where the IDs identity the source and operator nodes in the job graph between which the latency is being measured.

For example, I can determine the 95th percentile latency between the source and one of the sinks in a job I am running right now with this request:

```
http://localhost:8081/jobs/94b189a96b98b3aafaba6db6aa8b770b/metrics?get=latency.source_id.bc764cd8ddf7a0cff126f51c16239658.operator_id.fd0ee602f2fa8d310d9bd9f694e185f5.operator_subtask_index.0.latency_p95
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a ProcessFunction to add processing time timestamps to your events before they enter the CEP part of your job, and then use another ProcessFunction afterwards to measure the elapsed time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added the line of code to my Flink program but it still shows no metrics, neither for a job nor for a task manager. Do I have to enable metrics in general or do I miss something else?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to provide details on inspecting latency metrics.

Comment: Thanks for expanding your answer. I have now fully understood how I can access a job's metrics. But unfortunately I only receive empty responses when I use these queries with my respective job and operator ids. I have set the 'latencyTrackingInterval' to 10. But even the basic 'http://localhost:8081/jobs/<job-id>/metrics/' endpoint returns empty responses only. Does it matter that I try to get metrics for completed jobs?

Comment: Metrics reflect current state. You will need to setup a metrics reporter so that the metrics get persisted in an external metrics system -- see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/monitoring/metrics.html#reporter.

Comment: Also note that setting the latencyTrackingInterval to 10 could cause enormous overhead, especially as you scale up the job, since latency tracking markers are sent from every source instance to every operator instance. Sampling latency that often is not recommended. And most metrics systems can't handle that level of granularity.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to retrieve some latency stats. But I am still confused by the ids of the single operators. Where can I find out which id belongs to which operator? I didn't find them neither in the web dashboard nor in the task/jobmanager logs. Is it possible to provide constant ids for operators so that I can retrieve the latency stats via a constant id for different program runs?

Comment: The operators and their IDs are listed under vertices at http://<job_manager_rest_endpoint>/jobs/<job_id>/